# Separar hora e buscar entre datas dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

Tenho uma tabela contratos chamada **contrato** com duas colunas `data_ini` e `data_fim`.

`data_ini` e `data_fim` estão assim: 20/04/2014 10:46

Preciso fazer uma busca entre datas, sem a hora. Se não tivesse a hora eu conseguiria, mas com a hora esta difícil.

Estou tentando isso agora

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(data_ini, '%d/%m/%Y') FROM contrato
```

Comment: Amigão, estou navegando e tentando direito no mysql. O que achei agora e estou testando é SELECT DATE_FORMAT(data_ini, '%d/%m/%Y') FROM contrato

Answer (score 4):

O recomendado é utilizar campos `date` para data e `timestamp` para data e hora nas suas tabelas, campos de data como `varchar` tem varios problemas na ordenação e pesquisa. Para contornar essa situação use [str_to_date()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) que converte a string em um date, a consulta deve ficara assim:

```
SELECT * FROM contrato_reserva 
WHERE str_to_date(data_ini, "%d/%m/%Y") 
BETWEEN str_to_date('01/01/2011', "%d/%m/%Y")
and str_to_date('20/04/2014',"%d/%m/%Y")
```

Comment: Galera, veja se esta certo. Vou buscar entre as duas tabelas, data_ini e data fim.

    (SELECT * FROM `contrato_reserva` WHERE str_to_date(data_ini, '%d/%m/%Y') 
    BETWEEN str_to_date('14/09/2012', '%d/%m/%Y') and str_to_date('14/09/2012','%d/%m/%Y'))
      UNION ALL  
    (SELECT * FROM `contrato_reserva` WHERE str_to_date(data_fim, '%d/%m/%Y') 
    BETWEEN str_to_date('17/09/2012', '%d/%m/%Y') and str_to_date('17/09/2012','%d/%m/%Y'))


Exemplo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3827a5/5

Comment: Qual o problema? o que vc está tentando fazer?

Comment: Não busca corretamente

Comment: As datas de inicio e de fim estão em tabelas diferentes.

Answer (score 1):

Tente assim:

```
SELECT date_format(data_criado, '%d/%m/%Y') FROM contrato WHERE (2014-04-22 >= data_ini) AND (2014-04-22 <= data_fim);
```

Ou pode substituir a data por "NOW()", que é a data atual.
Eu uso isso para mostrar dados que estejam entre *data_ini* e *data_fim*.